# Inequality with $a+b+c=1$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, uvw, tangent-line-method

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R^+}$ such that $a+b+c=1$. Prove that $$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}+3(ab+bc+ca)\geq\frac{11}{2}.$$

I am trying to resolve this problem but actually i found some issues:
$$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}=3+\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\geq \frac{9}{2}$$
I only use Nesbitt's inequality. Then we only need that $3(ab+bc+ca)\geq 1$, but it is not correct, because $3(ab+bc+ca)\leq 1$.

Maybe some ideas will be more that grateful.

Comment: Let see using Cauchy $a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca$, by other hand: $(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)$ then $1-2(ab+bc+ca)\geq ab+bc+ca$ and we have $1\geq 3(ab+bc+ca)$

Comment: @A---B: Well, from $a+b+c=1$ I get by squaring $a^2+b^2+c^2+\color{red}{2}(ab+ac+bc)=1$. If your equation were true, it would mean $ab+ac+bc=0$. Which is easily contradicted by choosing $a=b=c=1/3$.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you replace $a+b$ by $1-c$ and analogously for the other two sums, and then get the thre fractions on a common denominator. I didn't try that to the end, but at least the numerator then gets very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}+3(ab+bc+ca)\geq \frac{11}{2}$$
Using $a+b+c=1$, this is equivalent to resolve:
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}+3(ab+bc+ca)\geq \frac{5}{2}$$
But we can use MA-MG in the expression:
$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{3}{2}(ab+ca)=\frac{2a^2}{3a(b+c)}+\frac{3a(b+c)}{2}\geq \sqrt{\frac{2a^2}{3a(b+c)}\cdot \frac{3a(b+c)}{2}}=2a$$
Similar to the above expression:
$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{3}{2}(ab+bc)\geq 2b$$
$$\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{3}{2}(ca+bc)\geq 2c$$
Then we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{3}\left \lbrace \frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{c}{a+b}\right\rbrace \geq \frac{1}{2}$$
And this is Nesbitt's inequality.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sum\frac{1}{a+b}+3(ab+bc+ca)\geq\frac{11}{2}$$

$$\sum\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{a+b}+\frac{3}{2}(1-\sum a^2)\geq\frac{11}{2}$$

$$\sum\frac{a^2}{b+c} + 4 +\frac{3}{2}(1-\sum a^2)\geq\frac{11}{2}$$

$$2\sum\frac{a^2(a+b+c)}{b+c}\geq3\sum a^2$$

$$2\sum\frac{a^3}{b+c}\geq\sum a^2$$

Using CSB we get:

$$(\sum\frac{a^3}{b+c})(\sum a(b+c))\geq(\sum a^2)^2 \geq (\sum a^2)(\sum ab)$$

and from that follows the inequality from above.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: The given inequality is equivalent to 
$$\sum_{cyc} \frac1{1-a} - \frac32\sum_{cyc}a^2 \ge 4 $$

which follows from noting that for $x \in (0, 1)$, 
$$f(x) = \frac1{1-x}-\frac32x^2-\frac43 -\frac54\left(x-\frac13\right) = \frac{(1+2x)(1-3x)^2}{12(1-x)}\geqslant 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.
We need to prove that
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^3\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2+3ab)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b)}+3(ab+ac+bc)\geq\frac{11}{2}(a+b+c)^2$$
which is fifth degree, which says that we need to prove a linear inequality of $w^3$,

which says that it's enough to prove the last inequality for an extremal value of $w^3$.

Since $a$, $b$ and $c$ are positive roots of the equation

$(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=0$ or $w^3=x^3-3ux^2+3v^2x$,

we see that $w^3$ gets an extremal value for equality case of two variables

or maybe for $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

1. $w^3\rightarrow0^+$.

Let $c\rightarrow0^+$ and since the last inequality is homogeneous, we can assume $b=1$,

which gives $2a^4-a^3-a+2\geq0$, which is obvious;

2. $b=c=1$, which gives $(a-1)^2(a^2+2a+2)\geq0$.

Done!

Answer (score 1):

We have $1=(a+b+c)^2=a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+bc+ca)$ and thus $$3(ab+bc+ca)=3/2-3/2(a^2+b^2+c^2)$$.

Using this and the fact you found, we find that an equivalent inequality is 
$$\frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c}-\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{3}{2}b^2-\frac{3}{2}a^2\geq1$$

Now $\frac{a}{1-a}\geq a(9/4a+3/4) $ (since $1/(1-a)\geq (9/4)a+3/4$) so we can conclude that

$$
\frac{a}{1-a}+\frac{b}{1-b}+\frac{c}{1-c}-\frac{3}{2}a^2-\frac{3}{2}b^2-\frac{3}{2}a^2\geq $$
$$\frac{3}{4}(a^2+b^2+c^2)+\frac{3}{4}(a+b+c)\geq$$
$$\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{4}=$$
$$1$$

And we're done.

**Intuition:**

I tried to go for an inequality of the form 
$$\frac{1}{1-a}\geq ax+y$$
in an effort to 'homogenize' the found inequality. Due to the fact that $1/(1-a)$ is convex, we have that any line tangent to its graph on $x\in [0,1)$ would be below it on that region. The reason I chose $$\frac{1}{1-a}\geq \frac{9}{4}a+\frac{3}{4}$$
was that I noticed that the first inequality had equality when $a=b=c=1/3$ and thus I wanted my middle-man inequality to also have equality when $a=1/3$ and thus chose the line tangent to $1/(1-a)$ at $a=1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

**Variational Approach**

Let $x=a+b$, $y=b+c$, and $z=c+a$. Then $x+y+z=2$ and we are minimizing
$$
\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z+3\left(1-\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}2\right)\tag{1}
$$
Furthermore, since $a+b+c=1$ and $a,b,c\ge0$, we have that $0\le x,y,z\le1$.

Since $x+y+z=2$, we get the restriction
$$
\delta x+\delta y+\delta z=0\tag{2}
$$
Taking the variation of $(1)$ gives
$$
\left(\frac1{x^2}+3x\right)\delta x+\left(\frac1{y^2}+3y\right)\delta y+\left(\frac1{z^2}+3z\right)\delta z=0\tag{3}
$$
Thus, to minimize $(1)$, we need to have $(3)$ whenever we have $(2)$. This means that
$$
\frac1{x^2}+3x=\frac1{y^2}+3y=\frac1{z^2}+3z\tag{4}
$$

---

**Case $\boldsymbol{1}$:** If $x\ne y$ and $y\ne z$ and $z\ne x$, then $(4)$ implies
$$
\frac{x+y}{x^2y^2}=\frac{y+z}{y^2z^2}=\frac{z+x}{z^2x^2}=3\tag{5}
$$
which implies that $x=y=z$.

---

**Case $\boldsymbol{2}$:** If $x=y\ne z$, then $2x+z=2$ and
$$
\frac{z+x}{z^2x^2}=3\implies12x^4-24x^3+12x^2+x-2=0\tag{6}
$$
Sturm's Theorem shows that there are no solutions to $(6)$ in $[0,1]$.

---

Therefore, $(1)$ is minimized when $x=y=z=\frac23$ and thus, $a=b=c=\frac13$. This means that
$$
\frac1{a+b}+\frac1{b+c}+\frac1{c+a}+3(ab+bc+ca)\ge\frac{11}2\tag{7}
$$